# Asociación de archivos múltiples en vscode para html y django-html

Tags: python, django, vscode

Estoy empezando con el framework de `django` y estoy usando **vscode** como editor.

Para hacer más rápido el desarrollo he instalado un paquete de autocompletado, para el cual modifiqué mi *settings.json* quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
"files.associations": {
    "**/*.html": "html",
    "**/templates/**/*.html": "django-html",
    "**/templates/**/*": "django-txt",
    "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements"
},
```

El cual funciona, y puedo usar commandos del paquete instalado, pero deja de autocompletar acciones propias de `html`, si el archivo settings.json lo cambio para poder reconocer estos comandos:

```
"files.associations": {
    "**/*.html": "html",
    "**/templates/**/*.html": "html",
    "**/templates/**/*": "django-txt",
    "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements"
},
```

Se corrige pero deja de funcionar los comandos del paquete instalado, mi duda es saber si existe la forma de asociar la extension `html` tanto para `html` como para `django-html`. He intentado copiar las llaves con diferentes valores pero da error por llave duplicada, también intenté separar ambos por espacios o comas pero no funciona, espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias